# C++ 11 - Is it safe when I pass a local variable as argument into a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

I have this code

```
#include <thread>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    short b;
}TestStruct;

void TestParamRef(const TestStruct& test)
{
    Sleep(3000); /*Sleep to wait for the caller function end*/

    TestStruct i = test; /*Test if the argument's still ok*/
}

void TestParamPointer(TestStruct* test)
{
    Sleep(4000); /*Sleep to wait for the caller function end*/

    TestStruct i = *test; /*Test if the argument's still ok*/
}

void Test()
{
    TestStruct localTest; /*Local variable should be destroyed after this Test function end*/
    localTest.a = localTest.b = 69;

    std::thread threadRef(TestParamRef, localTest);
    threadRef.detach(); /*Bye bye thread*/

    localTest.a = 6969;

    std::thread threadPointer(TestParamPointer, &localTest);
    threadPointer.detach();/*Bye bye thread*/

    localTest.b = 696969;
}

int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE  hInstance,
    HINSTANCE   hPrevInstance,
    LPTSTR      lpCmdLine,
    int     nCmdShow)
{
    Test();

    /*Put break point here*/
    return 0;
}
```

As you see in the code, I try to test what will happen if I pass a local variable into a thread, and this local variable is destroyed before the thread using it. And I find out that the TestParamPointer get a funny value (maybe because it's now pointing to the trash value), but the TestParamRef still get the right value.

So I wonder if the thread really store its argument in its own memory? I thought that when I use 'const TestStruct& test', the function won't copy the whole param but re-use that param (I use that when the param is pretty big - like the data of a sql table). So how did it work? Is it safe when I pass a local variable into a thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

std::thread will copy or move any argument you pass to it, so yes, it is thread safe.

Passing a raw pointer, on the other hand, is not thread-safe. In fact, passing a pointer to a local variable on a detached thread is doubly bad, because the thread is not guaranteed to complete before your local variable goes out of scope (you are not using .join() to block until thread is complete). Later on when the thread gets around to doing its work, it may or may not have something to work on, which can result in a crash.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

> The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If
>   a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has
>   to be wrapped (e.g. with std::ref or std::cref).

Also, if you do wrap a reference using std::ref, in general it becomes unsafe, because it can be accessed from the original context, so you're going to need to provide a synchronization method (mutex/lock, thread-safe container or what have you).

Comment: So what does it mean that in the example the reference is not passed using `std::ref`?

Comment: in my question example code, TestParamPointer  is not safe - concluded! But I used TestParamRef, Is it safe?

Comment: TestParamRef is safe, because you are just copying. A struct is "trivially copyable" so you don't need to do anything else fancy.

Comment: @123iamking Also, the reason you are getting a "funny value" is because you are assigning 696969 to a short. This is not valid.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm not sure about simple types, but I'm pretty sure for complex types it calls the copy constructor anyway. If you need pass by reference semantics guaranteed you need a reference_wrapper (which std::ref makes). Passing a pointer to a local variable into a detached thread is going to crash (or worse yet, not crash) in anything but a main function as his code stands.

Comment: Nice find Josh - and great to quote the Standard, but perhaps the wording could be improved to help explain the issue.  I.e. that it's the thread object itself that makes a copy of or moves the argument it's passed (when `std::ref`'s not used), then later when it starts the function running whatever by-value or by-reference arguments the spawned function itself has affects how it accesses (i.e. by ref or copy) the thread's copy of the local variable.

Comment: @TonyDelroy I added some words regarding when the copy happens, as well as explicitly calling out pointer to local variable issue.

Comment: @Josh: sweet... just one nit-pick: "std::thread will copy or move any reference you pass to it, so yes, it is thread safe" - I'd suggest "argument" or "variable" there, rather than reference.  The code passes the `localTest` argument with no caller-side references involved.